# Boxplot with respect to two factors using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, boxplot, ggplot2

I am very new to R and to any packages in R. I looked at the ggplot2 documentation but could not find this. I want a box plot of variable `boxthis` with respect to two factors `f1` and `f2`. That is suppose both `f1` and `f2` are factor variables and each of them takes two values and `boxthis` is a continuous variable. I want to get 4 boxplots on a graph, each corresponding to one combination from the possible combinations that `f1` and `f2` can take. I think using the basic functionality in R, this can be done by

```
> boxplot(boxthis ~ f1 * f2 , data = datasetname)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Please provide sample data, to in order to get precise answers.

Comment: This question would almost certainly be a better fit for stackoverflow.com, as there is little specifically statistical here.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can think of two ways to accomplish this:

*1. Create all combinations of `f1` and `f2` outside of the `ggplot`-function*

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(f1=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("m","w")), 
                 f2=factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.45), label=c("young","old")),
                 boxthis=rnorm(100))

df$f1f2 <- interaction(df$f1, df$f2)

ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f1f2), data = df) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

*2. use colour/fill/etc.*

```
ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1), data = df) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) I like the use of `interaction()`. Of note, we can specify `geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = .9))` to add extra space between boxplots.

Comment: You can also use  `dodge` argument in `ggplot` function - `ggplot(aes(y = boxthis, x = f2, fill = f1, dodge=f1), data = df) + geom_boxplot()`

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way:

```
ggplot(datasetname) + boxplot(aes(x=as.factor(f1),y=boxthis)) + facet_wrap(~as.factor(f2), nrow=5)
```

Gives something like the following:

[image: Faceted box plot]